# VS Cloud Load Test: Results are different (too much) each time run using same script

Tags: visual-studio, cloud, load-testing

**Update 2**

I resolved it by recording the new webtest, creating new loadtest file and run again. I don't know why but now it works and the number makes more sense.

**Update 1**

As comment from #AdrianHHH, I run another test with 120 users and see that the average page time reduce to 3.6s. This is our staging and I never finish loading within 5s before :(.

Web server info:

- ASW EC2 t1.micro
- RAM: 613 MB

Is the VS Cloud Load Test result reliable or not?

[[Fouth run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/symmR.png)]

=====================================================

**Original post**

I'm running a simple load test script to access my webpage with 100 users.

In my opinion, the **Total Requests** should be same if I run same script (same number of user, same config), but it does not.

I also attaches 3 pics that I used same script to run.

Please help. Thanks.

[First run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUhT5.png)

[Second run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vClTe.png)

[Third run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5qD8.png)

Comment: The load test results are reliable. The problem is probably elsewhere, as I said in my answer. Load testing is complex, there are many factors that can influence the observed performance. This is the wrong site to discuss the basics of load testing. You may get better help on sqa.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I has just resolved it by recording another webtest, making the new loadtest file. And these number seems make more sense. Many thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to expect identical results. Your tests run via network links that you have little control over and other network traffic may cause delays. Your tests run on servers where the processing times may vary depending on their other work. Load tests often include "think times" and Visual Studio provides a way of varying them to imitate the different speeds of different people.

The average page times and average response times vary widely between the three test runs. That supports the supposition that other factors are influencing the tests. To me these times are more worrying than the total requests.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As a newbie, I also confuse with these time number but I don't have any info to know it exact or not. I also make another run and update the post based on your comment, these number totally weird.